An example of an $L_p$ space with Borel measure and dimension larger than $\mathfrak c$
Given a normed space $X$, we can define the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $X$ as the smaller $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open (or closed) sets of $X$.
Suppose a measure $\mu$ is chosen in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$. We define the space $L_p(X)$, with $1\le p<\infty$, as the set of $p$-integrable measurable functions $f:X\to \mathbb K$ where $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$. In the space $L_p(X)$ we say that $f=g$ when $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$, except by a zero measure set.
With those definitions, my question is:
Is there an example of a normed space $X$ and a measure $\mu$ defined in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$ such that $X$ is $\sigma$-finite and the dimension of $L_p(X)$ is larger than $\mathfrak c$ (that is, the cardinality of $\mathbb R$)?
Of course, since we want a dimension larger than $\mathfrak c$, it is necessary and sufficient to prove that the cardinality of $L_p(X)$ is larger than $\mathfrak c$.

You can't prove that such a space exists. It is consistent with the usual axioms of set theory that every $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on a metric space is supported on a separable subspace.
This follows from the non-existence of real-valued measurable cardinals. A proof can be found, for example, in Appendix III of the first edition of "Convergence of Probability Measures" by Billingsley.

thanks for your answer and reference suggestion. Just some clarification: what do you mean by a measure being supported in a subspace?

I simply mean that there is a separable subspace of probability $1$.

If $X$ is any metric space and $\mu$ is the counting measure on the Borel $\sigma-$ algebera of $X$ then $1_{\{x\}}$ is in $L^{p}(\mu)$ for any $x \in X$. These are also linearly independent elements of $L^{p}(\mu)$. So the cardinality of $L^{p}(\mu)$ can be as large as we want. However, this is not the case if you insist on $\mu$ being $\sigma-$ finite.

Yes, of course, the counting measure does work for the cardinality part. With the $\sigma$-finite part, do you know if that example is impossible?
